# Infinite-scroll - jQuery won't work on new fetched elements

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

Basically I'm implementing the infinite-scroll (.com) on my WordPress blog and here's the code:

HTML

```
<div id="photos" class="display-fix">
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <img src="<?php $url = get_post_thumbnail_id(); $url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($url,'medium'); $url = $url[0]; echo $url; ?>">      
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<div id="pagination" class="clear right">        
    <?php if(function_exists('wpex_pagination')) { wpex_pagination(); } ?>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#photos').infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : ".next:last", // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden) 
    nextSelector : "a.next:last", // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2) 
    itemSelector : "#photos img", // selector for all items you'll retrieve 
    loading: {
        finished: undefined,
        finishedMsg: '',
        img: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/preloader.gif",
        msg: null,
        msgText: '',
        selector: null,
        speed: 'slow',
        start: undefined
    }
});

$('#photos img').hover(function(){
    alert('Works');
});
```

CSS

```
#photos {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}
#photos img {
    width: 504px;
    margin: 3px;
    float: left;
}
#infscr-loading {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    bottom: 10px;
}
#infscr-loading img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

What happens is that when the images pop up when I scroll down, the hover alert doesn't work, it only works on the first images displayed! The ones that popped up don't work.

Any reason why? I'm using `$(document).ready(function() {` should I use anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because hover event is attached to elements that are initially visible, just handle the finished event of `infinitescroll`:

```
$('#photos').infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : ".next:last", // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden) 
    nextSelector : "a.next:last", // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2) 
    itemSelector : "#photos img", // selector for all items you'll retrieve 
    loading: {
        finished: registerHover,
        finishedMsg: '',
        img: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/preloader.gif",
        msg: null,
        msgText: '',
        selector: null,
        speed: 'slow',
        start: undefined
    }
});

registerHover();

function registerHover()
{
    $('#photos img').hover(function(){
       alert('Works');
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mistype anything? Because this doesn't work, it breaks my whole JS.

Comment: @coldpumpkin maybe you just used it wrong? see the edit

Comment: Indeed, I was using it wrong, I didn't understand what you meant. It now works but only after the scroll is deployed! If I try it on the already visible images, it doesn't work. It makes sense, since it's only triggered after the infinite scroll js has worked. Any way to make it work for either before and after the js is deployed?

Comment: @coldpumpkin sure, just leave it at both places

Comment: isn't there a way to keep only one for both cases? like by using a var or something (I'm a noob at JS)

Comment: @coldpumpkin well, you could use a function and call it as much as you wish, see the edit

Answer (score 0):

You need to use delegation.

Change:

```
$('#photos img').hover(function(){
    alert('Works');
});
```

to

```
$('#photos img').on('mouseover', function(){
    alert('Works');
});
```